# Php sort 2 array keys the same way

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I'm struggling with a stupid issue i can't solve, probably because my head has just gone nuts. But really, i can't figure it out. It probably is simple than i think, but I wasn't able to find a solution on the web either.
I have this array, sorted like i want:

```
array (size=3)
  9 => float 124.58194
  2 => float 52.8428
  8 => float 25.041806
```

Then, another array has the same keys, but different order

```
array (size=3)
  8 => string '3' (length=1)
  9 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
```

Can i sort the second one by keys, using the order of the first one? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I tested it, but it will kill any keys in disciple that aren't available in master.

```
$master = array(
        9 => 999
    ,   2 => 222
    ,   8 => 888
);

$disciple = array(
        8 => 8989
    ,   9 => 9090
    ,   2 => 2020
);

$disciplined = discipline($master, $disciple);
var_dump($disciplined);

function discipline($master, $disciple) {
    $like_keys = array_intersect_key($master, $disciple);
    foreach($like_keys as $key => &$value) {
        $value = $disciple[$key];
    }
    return $like_keys;
}
```

Comment: A new meaning of zen coding?

Comment: @WaleedKhan haha yeah, was trying to think of a good name for the function